Acrylic on Inkjet Print
I would like to paint over an inkjet print with acrylic paint. How one would do this while making sure that the final artwork is "as archival as possible"?
I was thinking about spraying the print over with an inkjet print protective spray (for example the one Hahnemühle has for sale) first, and then applying the acrylic paint. I would then apply a layer of acrylic varnish once the work is done.

What type of paper are you using?
